# BIND zones and named files

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, bind

I've installed BIND in my Windows server2003. i've configured the named file in C:\named\etc\named.conf as:

```
options { 
    directory "c:\named\zones"; 
    allow-transfer { none; }; 
    recursion no; 
};

zone "tisdns.com" IN { 
    type master; 
    file "db.tisdns.com.txt"; 
    allow-transfer { none; }; 
};
```

My zone file is configured in C:\named\zones\db.tisdns.com.txt as:

```
$TTL 6h @ IN SOA ns1.tisdns.com. hostmaster.tisdns.co… ( 
         2010010901 
         10800 
         3600 
         604800 
         86400 )

@ NS ns1.tisdns.com.

ns1 IN A 192.168.0.17 mug IN A 192.168.0.103

key "rndc-key" { 
   algorithm hmac-md5; 
   secret "M0oW24WFQZhMu9wTq8qepw=="; 
};

controls { 
    inet 127.0.0.1 port 53 allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; }; };
```

In the above i've given the name to the domain as "tisdns". i want to create a new domain name in a different zone file. how can i create it?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "different domain in a different file" do you mean a subdomain of tisdns.com?  If so, you need to place NS records in your db.tisdns.com.txt (what a name...) file and just add another domain line.

Example to add to this file:

```
foo NS ns1.tisdns.com.
```

Then just add another zone:

```
zone "foo.tisdns.com" {
    type master;
    file "db.foo.tisdns.com.txt";
    allow-transfer { none; };
};
```

You will then need to place the SOA and NS records in this new file for this new zone.

Oh, and since you gave us your RNDC key, change it.  And perhaps learn a little about security.  That is a password, and you just gave it to us.

Comment: shouldn't this be zone "foo.tisdns.com"?

Answer (score 0):

for tisdns2.com add a line to your named.conf:

zone "tisdns2.com" IN { type master; file "db.tisdns2.com.txt"; allow-transfer { none; }; };

in db.tisdns2.com.txt:

$TTL 6h @ IN SOA ns1.tisdns2.com.

[etc.]

side note: don't forget to create a reverse dns lookup zone for your 192.168.0.0 network, unless you are aware of all the problems that could arise because you don't have one.